# How to optimize this code use in LINQ queries?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

Can I improve this below code use in LINQ queries? If someone has any idea about that please help me thanks.

```
var relatedtestDictionary = new Dictionary<Test, IList<Test>>();

foreach (var test in testArray)
{    
    var testResponse = this.testServiceRepository.GetAllLocationByCity(
      new AllByTestRequest { Test = test });

    relatedtestDictionary.Add(test, testResponse.test123);     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that (just use `ToDictionary()` if you want to create an new dictionary):

```
var relatedtestDictionary = testArray
  .ToDictionary(test => test,
                test => testServiceRepository.GetAllLocationByCity(new AllByTestRequest { Test = test })
                         .test123);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try